# Modifying the return value of an abstract method during runtime

Tags: java, abstract

Is it possible to modify the return value of an abstract method during runtime?

For instance:

```
public abstract class Task {
    public abstract boolean validate();

    public void setValidate(boolean b) {
        /* modify the return value of 'validate' method */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have a `boolean` field in `Task`, have `validate` return the value of that field, and have `setValidate` change that value?

```
public abstract class Task {
  private boolean isValid;
  public boolean validate() { return isValid; }
  public void setValidate(boolean b) { isValid = b; }
}
```

Comment: I wanted validate to be abstract since I'm going to be using this quite a bit in my upcoming project. 

That way I don't forget to set the validation.

Comment: Your only real alternatives are either this, or just not providing a `setValidate` method and requiring subclasses to implement `validate` themselves.

Comment: The subclasses do implement validate. Each subclass of Task will have their own validate methods, catered to their specific purpose. The point of the setValidate method would be to modify the requirements for this task to execute depending on other requirements.

Comment: Then those subclasses will have to do their own implementation of `setValidate` that looks like this version.  You can't rewrite methods at runtime like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, if only you could (easily, anyway). But there is a workaround if you can modify the abstract class and subclasses. Make subclasses implement a `protected` method instead, then make it so that your `validate()` method checks the value of the `validate` before validating. You should probably also make `validate()` a final method, as I have in the example, so that subclasses can't change it to *not* check the variable. This is up to you, of course.

Here's the code for the workaround:

```
public abstract class Task {

    private boolean validate = true;

    public final boolean validate() {
        // Assumes that no validation means validation always passes
        return validate ? validateImpl() : true;
    }

    protected abstract boolean validateImpl();

    public void setValidate(boolean validate) {
        this.validate = validate;
    }
}
```